# Button created in JS no event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I think is is a simple problem. What i did is to create a button 'remove' in JS when I click an a button 'add' and append it to a existing div.

This works well. BUT for the new created button 'remove' I want to fire a new event - the remove event. This didn't work. What is the problem here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
    $('#dateTimeSelector').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-link removedate" rel="contents" title="Termin entfernen">remove</button>');
  });

  $('.removedate').on('click', function() {
    console.log('remove #dateTimeBox_' + $(this).data());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">
  add
</button>
<div id=dateTimeSelector></div>
```

Comment: Learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), Use `$('#dateTimeSelector').on('click', '.removedate', function() {});`

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind the new removedate click event after placing on the page, so within the #mybutton click handler.

This is because when the click handler addition for removedate appens on page load, there are no matches in the jquery selector.